# Angular4 switchMap

Tags: java, angular

In my Angular 4 application the is a service as below which maintains booking object list. This booking list is a Subject.

```
    //imports

    @Injectable()
    export class BookingTreeService {
      selBooking: Booking;
      bookingList: Array<Booking> = [];
      bkgList$: Observable<Array<Booking>>;
      private bkgListSubject: Subject<any>;

      constructor( private resHttp: ResHttpService) {

        this.bkgListSubject = new Subject<Array<Booking>[]>();
        this.bkgList$ = this.bkgListSubject.asObservable();
      }

      loadBooking(bookingId:number): Observable<any> {
        let item = this.bookingList.filter(b => b.bookingId === bookingId);
        if (item && item.length > 0) {
         return this.retrieveBooking(bookingId); 
         // here, I don't want to call http call. Need to update the booking tree
        }
        else {
          return this.loadBookingAndLock(bookingId);
        }
      }

      loadBookingAndLock(bookingId: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.resHttp.loadBookingAndLock(bookingId)
          .map(response => {
            //handle response
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      retrieveBooking(bookingId: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.resHttp.retrieveBooking(bookingId)
          .map(response => {
            //handle response
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      addBooking(booking: Booking) {
        this.bookingList.push(booking);
        this.updateBookingTree(booking);
      }

      updateBookingTree(booking: Booking):void {
        this.bookingList.map((b:Booking) => {
          b.active = b.bookingId === booking.bookingId;
        });
        this.bkgListSubject.next(this.bookingList);
      }
    }
```

In the component I call the loadBooking inside ngOnInit as below.

```
loadBooking() {
    this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.bkgTreeService.loadBooking(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(
        response => {
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);

        }
      );
  }
```

If the selected booking is already includes in the booking tree don't want to call http request again, only want to update the booking tree. But inside the switchMap it accepts only Observable. So that how could it be handled?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you, in pseudo code, describe which behavior you would expect? Then it might be easier for us to translate that into proper Angular/RxJS code.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i understood is you want to cache the data, so for that you can use Rxjs Caching using **shareReplay**.

More details at :- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Answer (score 0):

You must store the booking list using "tap" when you make the call

```
loadBookingAndLock(bookingId: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.resHttp.loadBookingAndLock(bookingId)
       //When the observable finished
       .pipe(tap(response=>{
              //we concat the response to the bookingList
              if (!this.bookingList.find(b=>b.bookingId==bookingId)
                    this.bookingList.concat(response);
            }))
       .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```